# How to select all boxes using input type checkbox

Tags: javascript, c#, model-view-controller

[picture of my columns and checboxes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yumo2.png)

```
<table class="table table-striped grid-table">
    <tr>
        <th>Id</th>
        <th>Code</th>
        <th>
        <input type="checkbox" id="box"/>
        </th>
    </tr>
    @foreach (var item in (IEnumerable<cit.Models.getPersonPerName_Result>)Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>@item.idper</td>
            <td>@item.pername</td>
            <td>      

             <div class="pure-checkbox">
               <input type="checkbox" id="@item.idper" class="chk" checked="@(item.idperson == ViewBag.idperson ? true : false)" name="@item.id.ToString()" id="@item.id.ToString()" />
               <label for="@item.id.ToString()"></label>
             </div>

            </td>
        </tr>
    }
```

I have defined class `pure-checkbox`, so `item.idper` is my column with values of my document, and `item.pername` is my column with codes of my document, and there is `pure-checkbox` column which I  defined for `checkboxes` which i can check only one by one, but i want to check them all using input type on the code above.

Answer (score 0):

The way to to this is to listen for changes in the state of the 'master' checkbox. You can do this by attaching an event handler. When this handler is triggered you have to set the checked state of all other checkboxes to the checked state of the 'master' checkbox:

```
var selectAllBox = document.getElementById('box');
selectAllBox.addEventListener('click', function() {
    var pureCheckboxes = document.getElementsByClassName('chk');
  
  for(var i = 0; i < pureCheckboxes.length; i++) {
    pureCheckboxes[i].checked = this.checked;
  }
});
```

A working JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/TDucheyne/raxdzw1f/

Comment: Ok that's working, but when i reload my page checked boxes are not saved, is there any solution for that myb with AJAX or somehting else.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with a single line as

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#box").change(function(){  
    $(".chk").prop('checked',$(this).prop('checked'));
  });
});
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nauman0810/g5e10o2j/28/)